# Configure VEPA on Mellanox MLNX-OS MSN2700

Tags: switch, mellanox

Can anyone please help me with configuring reflective relay on Mellanox MLNX-OS MSN2700 (Mellanox switch)? This is to enable configuration of VEPA(Virtual Ethernet Port Aggregator).

I was able to find information for the same for cisco switches:
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/nexus9000/sw/7-x/layer2/configuration/guide/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide_7x/b_Cisco_Nexus_9000_Series_NX-OS_Layer_2_Switching_Configuration_Guide_7x_chapter_01011.pdf

but none for Mellanox.

Thank you!

Best Regards
Marc

Comment: Are you sure that Mellanox switch has this feature at all? After quick google looks like Mellanox PCIe cards have this feature however it looks like that mlnx-os doesn't support this.

Comment: @kubn2 thanks for the quick response. i was thinking it must be part of a typical switch. But as you said couldn't find the commands for this in the mellanox switch(mlnx-os). so i thought if they use a different terminology for e.g vepa/802.1qbg/evb/veb etc.